# Google Play Services sign in error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have been trying to run the example named buttonclicker2000: 
I set up everything and it works on a real device.
But on the emulator 4.2.2 when trying to sign in i get an unknown error.

here is the logcat
Can anyone help me out here?

```
07-17 20:40:41.293: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 20:40:50.233: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 20:40:51.743: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 20:40:51.873: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 20:41:03.104: E/Volley(748): [91] il.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
07-17 20:41:03.294: I/Choreographer(1780): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 20:41:03.384: I/Choreographer(1348): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 20:41:03.554: E/Volley(748): [91] il.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748): Access Not Configured
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748): aol
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at ajy.a(SourceFile:108)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at abm.a(SourceFile:213)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at abm.a(SourceFile:194)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at aav.a(SourceFile:486)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at aqu.a(SourceFile:221)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 20:41:03.614: E/SignInIntentService(748):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-17 20:41:04.594: I/Choreographer(580): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 20:41:05.063: D/ButtonClicker2000(1780): Sign-in failed.
07-17 20:41:05.083: I/Choreographer(1780): Skipped 189 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 20:41:05.443: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 20:41:05.613: I/Choreographer(1780): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 20:41:06.853: D/dalvikvm(1348): GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 36% free 2605K/4040K, paused 5ms+8ms, total 701ms
07-17 20:41:06.863: E/StrictMode(1348): class com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity; instances=2; limit=1
07-17 20:41:06.863: E/StrictMode(1348): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity; instances=2; limit=1
07-17 20:41:06.863: E/StrictMode(1348):     at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

EDIT
Full logcat, signout from all other devices from everywhere

```
07-17 22:01:00.997: I/ActivityManager(296): START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity (has extras)} from pid -1
07-17 22:01:01.007: W/WindowManager(296): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
07-17 22:01:01.187: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 22:01:01.367: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:01.737: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:01.937: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 22:01:01.948: I/Choreographer(296): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:02.007: I/Choreographer(296): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:02.018: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:02.547: I/Choreographer(296): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:02.557: I/ActivityManager(296): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: +1s313ms
07-17 22:01:02.627: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:02.687: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:03.237: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:03.287: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:03.627: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:03.817: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.057: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.107: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.237: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.267: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.417: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.507: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.597: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.727: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:04.867: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.058: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.197: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.217: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.377: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.547: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.697: D/dalvikvm(296): GC_CONCURRENT freed 683K, 56% free 5765K/13000K, paused 59ms+182ms, total 1675ms
07-17 22:01:05.717: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.807: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.877: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:05.947: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:06.017: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:06.087: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:06.177: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:06.317: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.048: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.307: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.397: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.527: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.547: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.697: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.728: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.837: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.877: D/dalvikvm(716): GC_CONCURRENT freed 333K, 12% free 3432K/3892K, paused 8ms+145ms, total 589ms
07-17 22:01:07.948: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:07.987: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.118: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.327: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.627: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.698: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.847: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:08.987: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.127: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.237: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.297: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.397: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.427: E/Volley(716): [76] il.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
07-17 22:01:09.447: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.537: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.687: E/Volley(716): [76] il.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716): Access Not Configured
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716): aol
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at ajy.a(SourceFile:108)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at abm.a(SourceFile:213)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at abm.a(SourceFile:194)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at aav.a(SourceFile:486)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at aqu.a(SourceFile:221)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 22:01:09.777: E/SignInIntentService(716):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-17 22:01:09.917: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:09.967: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.107: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.187: E/LoadSelfFragment(1283): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
07-17 22:01:10.197: W/WindowManager(296): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21020
07-17 22:01:10.227: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.267: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.408: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.537: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.937: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:10.947: I/Choreographer(689): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:11.087: I/Choreographer(1283): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:11.497: D/dalvikvm(1266): GC_CONCURRENT freed 425K, 12% free 4125K/4676K, paused 7ms+143ms, total 651ms
07-17 22:01:11.788: D/ButtonClicker2000(1266): Sign-in failed.
07-17 22:01:11.837: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 333 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:12.057: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-17 22:01:12.197: I/Choreographer(1266): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 22:01:13.017: D/dalvikvm(1283): GC_EXPLICIT freed 65K, 13% free 2535K/2904K, paused 5ms+154ms, total 442ms
07-17 22:01:13.067: E/StrictMode(1283): class com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity; instances=2; limit=1
07-17 22:01:13.067: E/StrictMode(1283): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity; instances=2; limit=1
07-17 22:01:13.067: E/StrictMode(1283):     at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Comment: the emulator does not have google play services on it

Comment: 4.2.2 does have google play services on it!

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this error in the past - I'm just struggling to be absolutely certain what caused it:

```
class com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity; instances=2; limit=1
```

I am fairly certain that it is because you are already signed on with that account on another device or emulator. I didn't have to do anything significant to fix the problem - sign out from the other device or use a different account. By the way if you do use a different account make sure it is defined as a tester for the game.

Update: I've just seen the full logcat and I see that this message precedes the one we have been focusing on:

```
Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

Your app_id must be set to the first 12 bytes of the client id from the developer console. This stuff is all well-documented by Google e.g.:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5936979195723776

If it is working on a real device and not an emulator then please also check that you have set up an emulator that contains the Google APIs.

Update:

You've now posted a different logcat ? Anyway, if you are still getting the client ID message please check that you do not have two different app_id values in your app (e.g. one in strings.xml and one in ids.xml )

Comment: Signed out from everywhere...still nothing :(

Comment: created a new account from the emulator still the same error.

Comment: When you say "nothing" what do you mean ? do you get the EXACT same error because that error is very specific and descriptive. I'm fairly certain that my answer worked for me. Make sure you have signed out on the real device as well. Is the new account Google Plus enabled ?

Comment: I'd also suggest shutting down and restarting that emulator ... just checking my notes ...

Comment: done all that, same error, infact if i use a different account on a real device, then also i get an unknown error. Do i have to publish my app to the market before i can use it from some other account on a real device?

Comment: No - it should be fine (I have tested it that way in the past). It is important that the accounts are Google Plus enabled and defined in your list of testers for the game on the Developer Console. Please post the full logcat.

Comment: aaahhh adding to the list of testers, i missed that step! let me get back to u

Comment: works with differnt account on real device, but still giving unkown error on emulator.

Comment: Think I've got it ... updating my answer now,

Comment: sorry, i just dont get it. I have added done the link the app and stuff. I got a app_id. I added the numbers only to the res/value/ids.xml. It works on my phone, but not on the emulator.

Comment: Fine as long as there is no other app_id defined in your strings. Please see my (latest) update to my answer.

Comment: i am using 4.2.2 which has google apis and google play services.

Comment: Just to clarify ... (please excuse me if you feel you have already answered this) ... the emulator can be 4.2.2 but when you define that emulator its target must be "Google API's..." . If your app is identical on both the real device and the emulator then this is likely to be the problem.

Comment: yes:) i am using "GOOGLE API" 4.2.2, eclipse. I exported as akp, got the SH1 number, linked my app. got the APP_ID, put in the res/value/ids.xml. Exported as .apk again using existing keystore and then emailed the app to myself. Downloaded it on my phone, it works.when i run using emulator and hit the sign in with google+ button, enter my id and password. It shows sigining in and unknown error. I have logged out from all my accounts. Even tried making a new account and after adding it to my tester list i tried to log in with the emulator gives unknown error. with the real device it works.

Comment: You've now posted a different logcat ?

Comment: I deleted everything and made everything again...new app_id n all. Works on real device, gives unkown error on emulator. With the same logcat as the one posted above. I am missing something really obvious or something is totally wrong with google. Like the GPS glitch of 2.3.3 while using emulator. In any case, i am giving up on working with emulator. Thanks a lot for giving this some time.

Comment: Okay i am back with another "discovery"

Comment: If i run the app using eclipse and usb cable to a real phone, after i hit the sign in button and provide username password, it does not work, shows unkown error . But if i dump the apk file of exactly the same app on to the phone n then install it, it works fine! I have no idea why this is happening but this is the case!!! so i am assuming if i push the apk file on the emulator and install it then it should work. I will try this later and post an update.

Comment: I get on two real devices error with code 10002 (SIGN_IN_FAILED), 'cause on those two devices I was logged in with one account. When I add this account as a tester - all signed in fine. Thanks!